# Get the names and count of all buckets in AWS S3

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm new to Boto3 and AWS API, and I want to get the list of buckets' names and the count of the available buckets in S3.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: All buckets or just your buckets?

Comment: All buckets. I need to monitor the total list of name and the count of the buckets.

Comment: The S3 API does not support listing buckets from other accounts unless you have explicit permissions. You can discover bucket names through DNS, but I don't know the specifics.

Comment: Yes, I can manage the permissions. I was wondering if there is a call I can use to grab the names into a list so I can use them to compare in my plugin for monitoring purposes; i.e. make sure that a specific list is always present and notify me when something changes...

Comment: If you have a specific list of buckets that you don't own, you can use `head_bucket` to check for existence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get all buckets in your account:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket_list = [bucket.name for bucket in s3.buckets.all()]
print len(bucket_list)
print bucket_list
```

Comment: Thanks for the tidy solution. I managed to get the list but with a more complex way. This is more efficient. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This script will help you to list all the bucket names and also get the count.

```
import boto 
from boto.s3.connection import OrdinaryCallingFormat

conn = boto.connect_s3(calling_format=OrdinaryCallingFormat())

count = 0

print ("Bucket names: ")

for bucket in conn.get_all_buckets():
    print (bucket.name)
    count = count + 1

print ("Total count of S3 bucket is ", count)
```

Note : please specify aws keys in script if you are not yet specified it in .boto file

Hope it helps !!

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I needed it in Boto3 and to list the names of the Buckets too.